# Django REST framework: Can a nested object access its parent object's details in a List View?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am attempting to implement a nested resource where one of its fields depends on a value from its parent resource.

Suppose we are building a system for a company which provides information about its customers plus sales figures for the company's salespeople.  So we have two models, **Customer** and **Rep**.  A rep can sell to more than one customer.

URL that returns all customers: `/api/1.0/customers/`

URL for a specific customer: `/api/1.0/customers/123/`

URL for customer-specific information for a specific sales rep : `/api/1.0/customers/123/rep/9/`

Note the rep URL contains the customer ID as well as the rep ID.

I want the customer URL to return a nested resource containing summary information about the rep, plus a hyperlink to full customer-specific information for that rep.  This is the output from the URL for all customers:

```
[
    {
        "id": 100, 
        "customer_name": "DolManSaxLil",
        "rep": {
                "id": 4,
                "annual_sales": 1500.01,
                "name": "Fred",
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/1.0/customer/100/rep/4/"
               }
    },
    {
        "id": 200, 
        "customer_name": "Hotblack",
        "rep": {
                "id": 4,
                "annual_sales": 10500.42,
                "name": "Fred",
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/1.0/customer/200/rep/4/"
               }
    }
]
```

To implement this we define two serializers:

```
class CustomerSummarySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = ...
    name = ...
    rep = RepSummarySerializer(read_only=True)

class RepSummarySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = ...
    annual_sales = ...
    name = ....
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_rep_url')
```

The problem I am facing is that I cannot work out how to access the current customer.id from the function `RepSummarySerializer.get_rep_url`.  It's possible in a Detail view as the customer is held in `self.parent.obj`:

```
def get_rep_url(self, obj):
    customer_id = self.parent.obj.id
    url = reverse('api_customer_rep', 
              kwargs={'customer_id': customer_id,
                      'rep_id': obj.id},
                      request=serializer.context.get('request'))
    return url
```

However, in a list view, `self.parent.obj` is a QuerySet of Customer objects and I can't see any way of identifying the current Customer.  Is there any way of doing this?  Have I missed something obvious?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Moment of clarity: the solution is to use a `SerializerMethodField` to instantiate the `RepSummarySerializer` and pass the `customer_id` in the context:

```
class CustomerSummarySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    id = ...
    name = ...
    rep = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_rep')


    def get_rep(self, obj):
        rep = obj.rep
        serializer_context = {'request': self.context.get('request'),
                              'customer_id': obj.id}
        serializer = RepSummarySerializer(rep, context=serializer_context)
        return serializer.data
```

The `customer_id` can now be accessed in `RepSummarySerializer.get_rep_url` like this:

```
def get_rep_url(self, obj):
    customer_id = self.context.get('customer_id')
    ...
```

Don't know why I didn't think of this three hours ago.

Comment: Quite an elegant solution. And works flawlessly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great solution, but I had to change rep = obj.rep to rep = obj.rep.get()

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer, if you use viewsets and want your sub-resource to be a collection (filtered by the parent document) only, you can also use the `@detail_route` decorator, as [documented in the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing):

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSummarySerializer

    ...

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def rep(self, request, pk=None):
        customer = self.get_object()
        queryset = customer.pk.all()
        instances = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        serializer = RepSummarySerializer(instances,
                context={'request': request}, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now you can query `/customers/123/rep/` and you will get a list of all `Rep` instances for the specified customer.

It probably won't fully solve what you need, but for many people that don't need full nested resources it's actually enough.