# Conditional Validation in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am exploring DRF and come with a problem that .I have my serializer class like .

```
class NodeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    cpu  = CpuSerializer(required = True)
    ram  = RamSerializer(required = True)
    hdd  = HddSerializer(required = True)
    ssd  = SsdSerializer(required = True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    type = serializers.ChoiceField(node_types)
    avg_iops = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
```

Now based on `type` my input can be different .Like if type is fixed my cpu input should be only integer and if type is variable my  cpu input would be

```
CpuSerializer.
```

I am trying to validate this condition under .

```
    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if data['type'] == 'fixed':
           do this 
        else:
            this is cpu serializer .
        return data
```

But again this way I am not able to verify the `CpuSerializer` keys .

Please help me out how can I do this in Django rest Framework .

Thanks

Comment: You are going to end up needing a custom field to handle this.

Comment: Check [Can a nested object access its parent object's details](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18539379/1693859) and its answer. Using a `SerializerMethodField` and passing the `type` to `CpuSerializer` should do the trick.